# LoginAction not working when using Acl in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am using ACL in my application. I have definned my loginAction in the beforeFilter in my AppController and still its not redirecting to the correct place. What i would like to do is when a users access the app like this - localhost/intraweb it must redirect then to localhost/intraweb/users/login

here is my AppController code

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'CustomFields.Field');

public $components = array(
'CustomFields.Field',
'Acl',
'Auth' => array(
'authorize' => array(
'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
)
),
'Session',
'Cookie',
);

public $uses = array('User');

public function beforeFilter() {       

//Configure AuthComponent
$this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
$this->Auth->allow('display');

//OTHER CODE

}
```

and here is my PagesController code

```
class PagesController extends AppController {

public function beforeFilter() {
parent::beforeFilter();
$this->Auth->allow();
}

//Other code
```

Does anyone have an idea why its not redirecting to the users/login page?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loginRedirect means action to call when Auth Session is not found. In simple terms a login page. The actions that are allowed to pass without Authentication being required will never redirect to loginRedirect.

When you access the `localhost/intraweb`, Cake will render `Pages/display` and since you have `$this->Auth->allow('display');` in your code. The Auth will let it render without redirection to the loginRedirect.

**Update:**

Redeclaring beforeFilter() in other controllers over-rides all the declaration in AppController. So, if the declarations from the beforeFilter() in AppController are to be inherited,

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter(); // inherit beforeFilter() from AppController
    // your controller specific declarations
}
```

Comment: i think i missing out something small here. i have edited my code and even removed the $this->Auth->allow('display'); . But still doesnt wanna redirect me to the login page. any idea on what might be causing this?

Comment: do you have beforeFilter() defined in PagesController ?

Comment: yes i had a beforeFilter() in my PagesController. i removed now works. Thank you

Comment: i have removed the beforeFilter in my PagesController and still the login action doesnt take me to the users/login page. I have edited my code above.

Comment: update the question with code from AppController and PagesController

Comment: you still have $this->Auth->allow(), PagesController/display does not require authentication, remove $this->Auth->allow("display") from AppController and $this->Auth->allow() from PagesController. Although, $this->Auth->allow() has an empty actions specified.

Comment: yes that seems to redirect me to the login page. Issue that i am having now is that im using Acl in my app and only administrators can login and when a normal user tries to login it just doesnt pass the login page